# Would it be possible to do replication using bucardo between different postgresql versions?

Tags: postgresql, debian, bucardo

We are having 2 database servers (Debian 8.3) with postgresql. 
1st server having postgresql 8.4 and 2nd server is having postgresql 9.4.

Would it be possible to setup bucardo between this 2 database servers?

Please let me know. 
Any hint will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Bucardo can replicate between different versions of Postgres. Bucardo 5.6 will work [from v8.1 to at least v12](https://bucardo.org/Bucardo/FAQ.html).

In fact Bucardo is used sometimes to upgrade PostgreSQL version without downtime.